# Как зациклить слайдер на нативном js

Tags: javascript, слайдер, карусель

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно прописать в условии, чтобы при достижении последней картинки, устанавливалась 1-ая. На данный момент происходит просто остановка.

```
const arrowRight = () => {
  if (display > bannerStore.getBanners().length - 1) 
  return document
    .getElementById('banner' + display)
    .setAttribute('style', 'margin-left: -100%');
  display++;
  renderDots(bannerStore.getBanners(), display);
  showButton();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let index = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if (index <= 4) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(index);
    index++;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
}, 1000)
```

```js
const arrowRight = () => {
  if (display > bannerStore.getBanners().length - 1) {
    return
    document
      .getElementById('banner' + display)
      .setAttribute('style', 'margin-left: -100%');
    display++;
    renderDots(bannerStore.getBanners(), display);
    showButton();
  } else {
    display = 1;
  }
};
```

Comment: не знаю, как правильно код в ответ вставить) только индексом он не подтягивает первую картинку почему-то

Comment: @Dasha, куда вставить, не понял?

Comment: это я про свой имела в виду, выше я его написала. Я Ваш код переписала под себя, но на первую картинку не переходит...